# Check multiple conditions on the same function output in Julia

Tags: julia

Is there a way to check multiple Boolean conditions against a value (to achieve the same as below) without computing `sum` twice or saving the result to a variable?

```
if sum(x) == 1 || sum(x) > 3
    # Do Something
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure why it's necessary to avoid a variable (maybe to avoid an additional line of code?) but you can do this: `if (s = sum(a)) == 1 || s > 3`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use one of several options:

Anonymous function:

```
if (i->i>3||i==1)(sum(x))
    # Do Something
end
```

Or,

```
if sum(x) |> i->i>3||i==1
    # Do Something
end
```

DeMorgan's theorem:

```
if !(3 >= sum(x) != 1)
    # Do Something
end
```

And if used inside a loop:

```
3 >= sum(x) != 1 && break
# Do Something
```

or as function return:

```
3 >= sum(x) != 1 && return false
```

But using a temporary variable would be the most readable of all:

```
s = sum(x)
if s > 3 || s == 1
    # Do Something 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Syntactically, a `let` is valid in that position, and the closest equivalent to AboAmmar's variant with a lambda:

```
if let s = sum(x)
       s == 1 || s > 3
   end
   # do something
end
```

I'd consider this rather unidiomatic, though.